# Array doesn't appear on render()

Tags: react-native

Hello I am trying to render some stuff dynamically and so far this is what I have:

```
render() {
    var contenido = [];
            contenido.push(
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>¿Acabas de tener un accidente?</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.sendAdjusterRequest}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'white'}}> Pedir ajustador </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>);
    return (
              contenido
            );
  }
}
```

After doing this nothing appears on my View, but it works when I do it like so:

```
return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>¿Acabas de tener un accidente?</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.sendAdjusterRequest}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}> Pedir ajustador </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        );
```

Why is it not working when I try return the elements as part of an array but works when I return them directly and how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render()` method **doesn't support rendering a return type of just an array directly**. When you call a `React` component's `render()` method it must return one of the following:

1. **React elements**. Typically created **via JSX**. For example, `<div />` and `<MyComponent />` are React elements that instruct React to render a DOM node, or another user-defined component, respectively.
2. **Arrays and fragments**. Let you return multiple elements from render. See the documentation on fragments for more details.
3. **Portals**. Let you render children into a different DOM subtree. See the documentation on portals for more details.
4. **String and numbers.** These are rendered as text nodes in the DOM.
   Booleans or null. Render nothing. (Mostly exists to support return test && `<Child />` pattern, where test is boolean.)

For more information check out the `render()` [spec](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render).

Your first option *isn't a valid rendering option*.. However, your second piece of code:

```
return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>¿Acabas de tener un accidente?</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.sendAdjusterRequest}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}> Pedir ajustador </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        );
```

is *returning a valid `React` element defined with `JSX`:* i.e. your parent `<View />` component.

If you want to return dynamic data with an array, a simple example would be something like the following:

```
render() {
    const studentClasses = ['math', 'science', 'history'];
    return(
        studentClasses.map(singleClass => (
           <li>{singleClass}</li>
        ));
    )  
}
```

Notice we are looping through the `studentClasses` array, which *could contain dynamic data from a database or api call*. Then we are taking advantage of the `.map()` function to create a new list item element on a per class basis.

The key thing to remember is you want to ***separate your data from your UI***. Then you can take advantage of dynamic template rendering helper functions like `.map()` on array objects.

Hopefully that helps!